# How to add static li inside dynamic list using php?

Tags: php, list, magento, foreach

I have 5 menu in the website which is coming dynamically :

> menu1 menu2 menu3 menu4 menu5

Now I want to add menu6 before menu5 using php.

My code:

```
    foreach ($collection as $category) {
        $i++;
        $menuCategory = $this->getCategoryAsArray($category, $currentCategory);
        $class = '';
        $class .= 'nav'. $i;
        if($i == 1) {
            $class .= ' first';
        } elseif ($i == $count) {
            $class .= ' last';
        }
        if($menuCategory['is_active']) {
            $class .= ' active';
        }
        //if($this->hasChildProduct($category)) {
            //$class .= ' parent';
        //}

        if($this->hasChildSubCategory($category)) {
            $class .= ' parent';
        }

        $class .= ' level-top';

        $html .= '<li class="level0 '. $class .'">';
        $html .= '<a href="'. $menuCategory['url'] .'">';
        $html .= '<span>'. $menuCategory['name'] .'</span>';
        $html .= '</a>';

        //if($this->hasChildProduct($category)) {
            //$html .= $this->getChildProductMenuHtml($category, $i);                
        //}

        if($this->hasChildSubCategory($category)) {                
            $html .= $this->getChildSubcategoryMenuHtml($category, $i);
        }

        $html .= '</li>';
    }
```

Menu6 is the static link which code is:

```
<li class="vertical-submenu" id="static-menu"><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('menu6')?>"><?php echo __('menu6')?></li>
```

Answer (score -2):

I am not getting the code because i am not aware of values coming in the array in foreach loop.

But I can explain the situation to you via Algorithm.

```
$i = 0;
foreach(expression){
  if(value == "menu5"){
    write("Menu 4")
  }
  Write("Menu ".$i)
  $i++;
}
```

Hope your problem is resolved with this. If you need anything else or want to elaborate more about you problem text me at shahrukhusmaani@gmail.com

Comment: write("Menu 4"); you mean menu6 which I want.

Comment: Lol yes menu 6, i mistyped it.

Comment: it is an algorithm bro.

Comment: write your own function for making <li> following the logic

Comment: Everything is not code. Soul is logic which is completely explained. Do not over react lol @NicoHaase .